# Facebook Login not working in iOS 13 in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-login, ios13

How to make Facebook Login work in iOS 13 in Objective-C? It's working in iOS 12 but not working in iOS 13 (it returns isCancellation true).

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Comment: Although many things has changed since Ios 13 update im not sure why facebook "Login" is not working . , are you sure you are using the correct Facebook App Id . Also if you are getting any error or stacktrace could u provide it to us .

Comment: Yes, Facebook App Id is correct as it is working in iOS 12. In iOS 13 it returns isCancellation true

Answer (score 1):

if you have created app in xCode 11 please follow me.

**IMPORTANT-** import FBSDKLoginKit   in sceneDelegate file.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
enter code here
  guard let url = URLContexts.first?.url else { return }
    
  let _ = ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
        UIApplication.shared,
        open: url,
        sourceApplication: nil,
        annotation: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the current FBSDK should resolve the problem.

FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/BridgeAPI/FBSDKBridgeAPI.m was modified to support iOS 13's requirement to implement ASWebAuthenticationPresentationContextProviding in FBSDKCoreKit 5.4. The current version is 5.8. Versions prior will no longer work.

The needed change is posted here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/commit/6b061099f339ef0e8bde2e2c2163ef5a3c1b8340#diff-72593591275d63edfb1bfad837e4c32f

Answer (score -2):

Just add the following code below 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' delegate method in AppDelegate. It works with latest Facebook SDK and iOS 13 as well. Comment if anyone gets an error.

```
func application(
        _ app: UIApplication,
        open url: URL,
        options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]
    ) -> Bool {
        return ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            app,
            open: url,
            options: options
        )
    }
```